# Connection reset when consuming CXF Service (ssl .net)

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf, asmx

I'm fighting with this issue and Stackoveflow and Google failed me so far.
I am consuming a ssl .NET service in Spring but I get a:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
(...)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SocketException invoking https://address/service/servicews.asmx: Connection reset
```

I my configuration is following:

```
<jaxws:client
        id="service"
        serviceClass="com.(...).service.SomenameSoap"
        address="${environment.facade.xxx.service.address}">

    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/>
                    <entry key="user" value="${environment.facade.xxx.service.auth.header.user}"/>
                    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
                    <entry key="addUTElements" value="Nonce Created"/>
                    <entry key="passwordCallbackRef" value-ref="securityCallbackHandler"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>

    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature"/>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>

<http:conduit name="{http://tempuri.org/}servicePortNamePort.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="${environment.facade.xxx.service.disableCNCheck}">
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="xxx" resource="/certificates/truststore.jks"/>
        </sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
        </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

When I run a Spring test I get a following exception:

```
2015-08-21 11:54:53,491 WARN [main] [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain:443] - <Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}SomeserviceSoapService#{http://tempuri.org/}Method has thrown exception, unwinding now>
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:137)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.validateXXX(Unknown Source)
    at com.(...).Facade.createXXX(XXX.java:31)
    at com.(...).FacadeTest.testCreateXXX(FacadeTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SocketException invoking https://address/service/servicews.asmx: Connection reset
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1474)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1459)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:229)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:660)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol
```

I am running CXF 2.6.16 and code is beeing compiled with java 1.5.
I have read about chunking issues and added  to my conduit configuration and it results in another exception:

```
2015-08-21 12:07:45,900 WARN [main] [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain:443] - <Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/}SomeserviceSoapService#{http://tempuri.org/}Method has thrown exception, unwinding now>
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: Connection reset
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I can conume this service in Soap UI using the same truststore and creditentials.
Help me Stackoverflow you are my only help.

Comment: What version of Java run-time is being used?

Answer (score 0):

In `tlsClientParameters`, include element `secureSocketProtocol` with value "TLS" (see [CXF TLS Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html)).

Also, for the sake of eliminating cipher suite availability being an issue, try including all cipher suites with this lone wild-card inclusion filter:

```
<sec:include>.*</sec:include>
```

If connection is still being reset, enable the following system property:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

Examine standard output and post what was received from server immediately prior to connection reset.

Alas, it may well be that the SSL/TLS protocol and cipher suites allowed by the server may not be supported by such an old Java run-time.